# How to read the first line of a subprocess without buffers filling up in Python

Tags: python, linux

From Python in Linux, I want to start a sub-process, wait until it prints one line on it's standard out, then continue with the rest of my Python script.  If I do:

```
from subprocess import *

proc = Popen(my_process, stdout=PIPE)
proc.readline()

# Now continue with the rest of my script
```

Will my process eventually block if it writes a lot to its stdout, because the pipe fills up?

Ideally, I'd like the rest of the output to go to the standard output of my script.  Is there a way to change the stdout of the subprocess from PIPE to my standard output after it starts?

I'm guessing I'll have to spawn a separate thread just to read from my process's stdout and print to my own, but I'd like to avoid that if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: You can use the source/sink pattern. See http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf

Comment: You'll need a separate thread if you want to filter the first line and send the rest to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the process?

```
proc.terminate()
```

After the readline

Answer (score 0):

The readline method should not block if the line is particularly large, this is pulling data directly out of the pipe buffer and into userspace. If the data was remaining in the pipe buffer, there's a good chance it would block the spawned process but I'm pretty sure Python must take the data out of the pipe buffer before it can examine it for the end-of-line.

Or you could just read characters off the pipe directly, this would prevent any possible buffer issues:

```
from subprocess import *
proc = Popen(my_process, stdout=PIPE)
c = ' '
while c != '\n':
    c = proc.stdout.read(1)
# Now complete the rest of the program....
```